# CSS calc percentage width and division

Tags: html, css, css-calc

I have menu which is a list with three list-items:

```
<ul class="menu_container">
  <li class="item">Item1</li>
  <li class="item">Item2</li>
  <li class="item">Item3</li>
</ul>
```

The width of the ul element changes as you resize the browser and I'm trying to use calc to workout the widths of the items so that they are equal. The first and third list-items have a 2px wide left and right border.

In the Chrome dev tools the width of menu_container is 636px. If I inspect the first list-item and do `width: 100%` it shows 640px. But if I do `calc((100% - 12px) / 3)` it shows 212px for the width. Why is this not (640 - 12) / 3 = 209.333?

Comment: did you add `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I wanted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Box-sizing:border-box**

> With box-sizing:border-box the dimension is calculated as, width = border + padding + width
>   of the content, and height = border + padding + height of the content.

**Example**

width = `100px + 2px` border on both side = `4px` + padding `5px` on both side = `10px`

The total will be `100px + 4px + 10px` = `114px`

With `box-sizing:borderbox` property

The total will be `100px` because the `border` and `padding` is given from inside